# why does this grep command have no output?

Tags: grep

If I use a grep command like this `ls | grep '^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$'` to match filenames, it outputs no result but when the command changes to `ls | grep '^[-[:alnum:]\._]*$'`, it works correctly. What's going on?

Comment: `*` = 0 or more. `+` = one or more. so obviously your `+` regex matched nothing.

Comment: i know that but filenames must match one or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep uses ["basic"](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended) regexes by [default](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs), where `+` is a normal character. You need `\+` to match 1 or more things (or use `grep -E`).